# Excluding javascript/whitelisting IP with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, maxmind

I currently use PHP to call a geoip database to redirect users based on the state their IP address resolved to.

I'm now switching to a javascript API that calls maxmind's database.

The problem: I don't know how to whitelist my own IP address.

Here is the old PHP code no longer in use:

```
include_once("/home/censor/geoip/geoipcity.inc");

$gi = geoip_open("/home/censor/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
$record = geoip_record_by_addr($gi,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
geoip_close($gi);

if((trim($record->region)=="WA") && ($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]!="11.111.111.111")) {   
  header("Location: http://www.google.com"); /* Redirect browser */   
  exit;
}
```

The 11.111.111.111 is the whitelisted IP address.

Here is the new, javascript code:

```
<script src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var redirect = (function () {
    /* This implements the actual redirection. */
    var redirectBrowser = function (site) {
        var uri = "http://" + site + ".google.com/";
        window.location = uri;
    };

    /* These are the country codes for the countries we have sites for.
     * We will check to see if a visitor is coming from one of these countries.
     * If they are, we redirect them to the country-specific site. If not, we
     * redirect them to world.example.com */
    var sites = {
        "WA": true

    };
    var defaultSite = "www";

    var onSuccess = function (geoipResponse) {
        /* There's no guarantee that a successful response object
         * has any particular property, so we need to code defensively. */
        if (!geoipResponse.city.iso_code) {
            redirectBrowser("www");
            return;
        }

        /* ISO country codes are in upper case. */
        var code = geoipResponse.city.iso_code.toLowerCase();

        if ( sites[code] ) {
            redirectBrowser(code);
        }
        else {
            redirectBrowser("www");
        }
    };

    /* We don't really care what the error is, we'll send them
     * to the default site. */
    var onError = function (error) {
        redirectBrowser("www");
    };

    return function () {
        geoip2.city( onSuccess, onError );
    };
}());

redirect();
</script>
```

Would someone be able to provide me with a way to whitelist an IP address using the new code? I'm not fluent at all in PHP or Javascript, so help is extremely appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If this javascript code is inline in a PHP file (which it sounds like it is) you can replace this:

```
if ( sites[code] ) {
```

with this:

```
if (sites[code] && "<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" !== "11.111.111.111") {
```

---

OP has specified that the javascript code is *not* inline. In that case, you can modify the code from this:

```
if ( sites[code] ) {
```

to this:

```
if (sites[code] && userIp !== "11.111.111.111") {
```

Where `11.111.111.111` is the IP you want to whitelist. Then, in your PHP, include this script:

```
<script>
    var userIp = "<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I just realized this is going to be in it's own directory in a .js file. Any way to use PHP to not reference the file if it matches the address? Thank you, Adam.

Comment: @brenda Glad I could help! If this solved your problem, I'd appreciate if you clicked the little check mark to the right of my answer :)